# How to change splash screen in portable xamarin ios project?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, splash-screen

I am using portable xamarin form in which one the project is IOS porject

In IOS project I want to create splash screen. I added Iphone Launches images and iPad launched images in ios project property.

when i run the application it show default splash screen.

I also try by removing launchscreen tag from info.plist file, when i run application splash screen is displaying but header and footer become black

Please suggest me how to change the splashscreen of the ios project

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Facing the same issue, but didn't find any solution for the same. Any luck so far ?

Answer (score 5):

At first you should know, that the splash screen is just a static image, you can set it by this step:

1 Create a single view application:
[image]

2 Going to "info.plist" you can find "launch images", click "Use Asset Catalog":
[image]

3 Then remove the "LaunchScreen.storyboard" from your solution, and remove the Key "Launch screen interface file base name" from the info.plist->source:
[image]
[image]

4 At last set the image you want in "Assets.xcassets":
[image]

Oh, another thing, if you need change anything in "Assets.xcassets" you'd batter:

1 Clean your solution and rebuild it;

2 Delete the APP from your device if you already install the old one;

3 Then install the new one, it will works.

Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Add one xib file and setup your launch screen image in that xib file with UIImageview, and then assign that file to"Launch Screen File"
Check attached screenshot for help.[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's the way to set the launch images for Native development in XCode, not for Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: For creating build or submit app to app store you use xcode only, right?

Comment: No, if you using Xamarin.iOS you don't need to open XCode at all, just using Xamarin Studio to archive and submit it.

Comment: Step 2 - I don't have the option for Use Asset Catalog - now what?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put a image to fill any screen size without open Xcode:

Go to your Resources -> LaunchScreen.storyboard file

- Right click to your "LaunchScreen.storyboard" file -> Open Width -> Source Code Editor

Replace your Storyboard code with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14109" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="X5k-f2-b5h">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14088"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="gAE-YM-kbH">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="X5k-f2-b5h" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="Y8P-hJ-Z43"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="9ZL-r4-8FZ"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="yd7-JS-zBw">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <imageView userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" fixedFrame="YES" image="background1.png" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="7Bm-if-fjC">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                            </imageView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.20392156862745098" green="0.59607843137254901" blue="0.85882352941176465" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="XAI-xm-WK6" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="348" y="338.68065967016497"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <image name="background1.png" width="2560" height="1600"/>
    </resources>
</document>
```

- Where you see "background1.png" put the name of your background resource image file that should be located in the Resources Folder of your Xamarin.ios project.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are connected to your external Mac. Then double click Launchscreen.storyboard in your iOS-project. You should get a design-view of the Splashscreen.