# Why is my image resizing when I switch device?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, autolayout

So I've set all the constraints yet my image keeps resizing, why is this?
This is what it looks like when I resize.

[image: Visual Studio PC]

Comment: Please, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the code for the same. (A gif or a screenshot don't count.)

Comment: There is no code for the UI, had it been Android then it would be some XAML. This is for the iOS sotryboard.

Comment: Is there anything else you can share? You say you've "set all the constraints", so, at least there is some way for you to show us?

Comment: It shows the lines (constraints) in the gif @IsmaelMiguel

Comment: You can see in the gif that I've set the constraints because there are those blue lines indicating that,

Comment: @MarkDenom you can also see a lot of exclamation marks and such on those lines. It might be worth checking out what they say.

Comment: This helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39745794/how-to-change-splash-screen-in-portable-xamarin-ios-project